# Integration Services node missing for LocalDb

Tags: sql, ssis, ssms, etl, sql-server-2019

I'm having an issue deploying an SSIS package to a localdb server instance i created.  When i try to deploy to the server from my integration services project in VS, i get the error below:

[image: Visual Studio error when I attempt deploying SSIS package]

So i connected to the localdb in SSMS and noticed that the entire Integration Service Catalogs node is missing.  I reinstalled SQL Server 2019 and made sure that integration services, database engine services, and client tools SDK was checked in the features list and installed and its still missing:

[image]

I've found other posts on stackoverflow regarding a similar issue but most seemed to be in regards to old versions of SSMS.  I have the latest build of SSMS installed.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: im running the Developer version of SQL Server 2019

Comment: LocalDB doesn't support SSIS. SSIS in only supported in Standard and above.

Comment: @Larnu ok i was afraid of that.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: *"im running the Developer version of SQL Server 2019"* LocalDB isn't the developer edition. Developer Edition is Developer Edition (to state the obvious). LocalDB is the most minimal version of SQL Server. You aren't running the Developer version.

Comment: @Larnu i have both installed. im new to SSIS and database management in general so i installed LocalDB with hopes of testing out a SSIS package i created for practice purposes on my local machine before attempting to deploy anything to any of our QA servers.